# How do I find out a server's load?

Tags: load, lamp, statistics

I'm creating a php script that will capture certain information from the server and database at regular intervals. The server is running LAMP.

Is there a way to output the server load, or other statistics that may indicate the performance or load on the server including mysql?

Comment: What do you mean by "load"?  CPU use?  I/O use?  Network use?

Comment: Actually, I'm referring to cpu load and mysql database load. Those are what matters right?

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
cat /proc/loadavg
```

or

```
uptime
```

which printout the current load of the servers 1 min / 10 min / 15 min interval.

May be you should take a look to http://munin-monitoring.org/ or may be nagios

Comment: thank you! with your help i managed to find php function sys_getloadavg(). Do you know how I may determine the mysql database load? say...available connections vs max connection limit? thanks :)